# Why is my NSSet coming up empty?

Tags: ios, segue, nsset

I am working on an app that opens with a tableView, once a cell is selected the user is taken to a second tableView of options related to the first cell selected in the first tableView. On the second tableView, the user should select one more cell and will be taken to a detail view.

I have the first tableView showing up properly and the second tableView is also displaying what it should. The problem is selecting something on the second tableView and being taken to the detail view. The detail view screen comes up, but it is empty.

I have tried adding NSLogs to see if my NSSet contains anything, but it doesn't seem to show anything. I have looked into the sql file and it does contain the data, so I know it has been written in, my only problem is accessing it.

My code for the prepareForSegue on the second tableView screen is below. Could you please tell me if you see anything terribly wrong.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toExplanation"]) {


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ExplanationViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSSet *optionChoices = [[self threeScreen] theOptions];
    _selectionContent = [optionChoices allObjects];
    NSLog(@"%@",[optionChoices allObjects]);
    NSSortDescriptor *nameSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortedChoices = [optionChoices sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:nameSort]];
    NSLog(@"%@", sortedChoices);


    Option *option = [sortedChoices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    destViewController.explainToMe = option.explanation;
    //destViewController.explainToMe = @"Working?";
    NSLog(@"%@",option.explanation);

}
```

If I uncomment 'destViewController.explaintToMe = @"Working?"; I can see 'Working?' in the detailView.

Comment: So when you log, the optionChoices is empty?

Comment: Does `indexPathForSelectedRow` actually return the correct index path or has the cell selection been cancelled by the time this method is called?

Comment: @verbumdei, Yes, optionChoices is empty. Is that a problem with how I am attempting to get the asset?
Wain, Where would I return the correct index path if I don't do it here?

Comment: then shouldn't you check the line `[[self threeScreen] theOptions]` instead?